# Continue in a run block in Kotlin

Tags: java, loops, kotlin, continue

I'm trying to convert the following Java code to Kotlin in an idiomatic way:

```
for (Group group : groups) {
    String groupName = group.getName();
    if (groupName == null) {
        warn("Group name is null for group " + group.getId());
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried the following

```
for (group in groups) {
    val groupName = group.name ?: run {
        warn("Group name is null for group ${group.id}!")
        continue
    }
    ...
}
```

However this will not compile with the error:

> 'break' or 'continue' jumps across a function or class boundary

So my question is, is there a better way to write this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Normally `continue` can be also emulated via `::filter`.

But since in this case you need also a warning, this makes the classic `for` the best solution.

However there are some alternatives.

```
groups.filter { group -> when(group.name) {
        null -> {
            warn("Group name is null for group ${group.id}!")
            false
        }
        else -> true
    }.for Each {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or use `return@forEach`.

But again, in this case a classic `for` is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your code too much, just use the good old `if`

```
for (group in groups) {
    val groupName = group.name

    if (groupName == null) {
        warn("Group name is null for group ${group.id}!")
        continue
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same java code can be implemented like this.

```
for (group in groups) {
    val groupName = group.name
    if(groupName == nul){
      warn("Group name is null for group ${group.id}!")
      continue
    }
    ...
}
```

However, you can continue to top loop or other loops in **Kotlin** by giving labels.

```
loop@ for (i in 1..100) {
    for (j in 1..100) {
        if (...) continue@loop
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can't implement `continue` in lambda functions. But you can use `return` alternatively.

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach lit@{
        if (it == 3) return@lit // local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop
        print(it)
    }
    print(" done with explicit label")
}
```

**Output:**

```
1245 done with explicit label
```

**Reference:**
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a very satisfying and idiomatic solution:

```
groups.forEach { group ->
    val groupName = group.name ?: run {
        warn("Group name is null for group ${group.id}!")
        return@forEach
    }
    ...
}
```